# I have a check constraint on my SQL server, how do i set a validation for the Check Constraint in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

The definition for the check constraint is

```
 (NOT [alt_code1] collate Latin1_General_BIN like '%[^-0-9A-Z_/&$!]%')
```

How do i make that validation in c#?
Also, is collate Latin1_General_BIN case sensitive?

```
private void txtAlt_Code1_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

Comment: It is case sensitive, due to the _BIN part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i found this code to be working

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[^-0-9A-Z_/&$!]");
                Match match = regex.Match(input);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    // raise error
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Regular Expression`

```
var regex = @"^[-0-9A-Z_/&]$!";
var match = Regex.Match(input, regex);

if (!match.Success)
{
    // raise error
}
```

Comment: You need to escape the square brackets